# Strange request to https://settings.luckyorange.com/ from Angular polyfills.js bundle in the browser console

Tags: angular, polyfills, spartacus-storefront

We are using Angular v10 with Spartacus v3.4.10 (behavior was observed also on Angular v11) and we saw that a strange request to https://settings.luckyorange.com/__some_hash__ that was returning a 404. Does anybody know anything about this?

We ran the application in production mode with SSR and waited aprox. 10 seconds and watched the browser console.

Comment: a quick google shows that luckyorange.com provide stats for websites (I'm guessing like google Analytics) check your index.html file or do a search to find where it is in the angular app.

Comment: true, seems not to be angular or spartacus related but an integration. The source file was a little misleading because it seemed to be from polyfills.js. Thanks